# How to apply layout and templates to other controller folder?

Tags: grails, gsp

I want to apply my layouts/main.gsp layout to the user/login page. 
my main.gsp has reference to other css and refernces to the templates :

```
</head>

<body>

<g:render template = "templates/headerTop" contextPath = "/"></g:render>

<g:render template = "templates/menuHeader" contextPath = "/"></g:render>
<g:layoutBody/>
<g:render template="templates/footer" contextPath = "/"></g:render>

</body>
```

But when i run the application and go to login click it says it can not find the template path. I understand that since login is in 'user' folder so it is not able to search the path. 
Question is : how to apply layout to my login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify absolute path to your templates:

```
   <g:render template = "/templates/headerTop" contextPath = "/"></g:render>
```